# Change one word in lots of HTML pages with another word from a list of words

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, batch-processing

I have about 2000 HTML pages (all pages have the same content except for the city name). I have the list of city names, and i need each page to have 1 city name.
How can I change the City name in each page?

city name list: birmingham
montgomery
mobile
huntsville
tuscaloosa
hoover.. etc...

and I need to make each page like this:
title: birmingham,
next page;
title: montgomery,
and so on.

I need the change to happen in the title:Example (City Name)
and in 2 other h2 tags.

Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: You need to provide more information on how you're trying to accomplish this: offline, by batch processing HTML files, or online - at runtime, in the browser?

Also, have you considered using a templating language to generate that HTML content dynamically, based on that list of cities?

Comment: offline... I'm wondering if there is any way to automate the process, at present I'm just opening each page and CTRL+H and replacing each city name.

Comment: Wrong tags.. Corrected to match the query..

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** 
This script is for the existing files. It will hierarchically find all the `index.html` files in the current directory and will replace the "string_to_replace" string with that file's parent directory's name which is the city name in your case. It will also make that name capitalized before the replacement.
Feel free to update the tamplate_string variable value in the script so that it fits to the string which is used in your index.html files in place of the city name.

```
#!/bin/bash
template_string="string_to_replace"
current_dir=`pwd`
find $current_dir -name 'index.html' | while read file; do
    dir=`basename $(dirname "$file")`
    city="$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< ${dir:0:1})${dir:1}"
    sed -i -e 's/'$template_string'/'$city'/g' $file
done
```

**Initial answer:**
My initial suggestion is to use a bash script (e.g. script.sh) similar to this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    file="./cities.txt"
    template="./template.html"
    template_string="string_to_replace"
    while IFS= read line
    do
            cp $template $line".html"
            sed -i -e 's/'$template_string'/'$line'/g' $line".html"
            echo "$line"
    done <"$file"
```

and run it from bash terminal:

```
$ source script.sh
```

What you need to have:

1. *cities.txt* with cities names list, e.g.

   London

   Yerevan

   Berlin
2. *template.html* with the html template you need to have in each file. Make sure the city name is set as "string_to_replace" in it, e.g. title: string_to_replace

Since you did not mention anything related to the files names, the files will be named like London.html, Yerevan.html,...

Let me know in case you don't need to create new files, and need to make replacement in the existing ones. In this case we'll need to update the script a bit after you tell me how you know which string is going to be used in the exact file.

Comment: thank your for your answer. All the files are created (filename is index.html).

Comment: How do you decide to use the city name for the exact index.html? Does it depend on the directory name? I can help in case you provide some details.

Comment: Do you just get the next city name from the list and randomly put in one of  index.html files?

Comment: this is what i need to do: for each US state i have to make a folder, in every state folder i need subfolders for every city, and in the subfolders i need to put a index.html(for all cities the content is the same exept for the city name)

Comment: Can I assume that subfolder's name is the city name? That will help to take it automatically and use in the corresponding index.html

Comment: yes. I'll give you an example michigan/detroit/index.html(and in here i need to put Detroit in the title tag of the page, and in 2 other h2 tags)

Comment: I will update comment a bit later in order to fit your current requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much... i have to make about 7000 of these pages.. and any automation of the process would be very helpful. Thank you again! and I will be here when you replay.

Comment: I've just updated my comment. Please take a look and let me know in case you have any questions.

Comment: thank you every much for your answer, just one question... how do I run the script ?

Comment: Are you familiar with bash terminal? Which OS do you use?